# How to extend user's properties for the server session in nextauth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

After the user logs in, I am adding the ID of the user to the session.
When I get the session from a client side component, every thing looks good.
But when I try to reach the session from a server side component, it only shows, user whit name and email.

Here is how the route.ts looks like

```
export const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      //...,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.name = token.name;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
});
```

And I am trying to get the session on a server side component like this:

```
import { Session, getServerSession } from "next-auth";
const session: Session | null = await getServerSession(handler);
```

I made sure that it is working for client-side.